# Flutter DataTable get all row values

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a data table in which every row could be editable. I need to make a submit button that saves all changes in the table. But I can't figure out how to get all rows in the table.

```
    TextButton(
         style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              primary: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
              print(table1.rows());
          },
          child: Text(
              "Save all changes",
          ),
),
```

And DataTable with the key "table1";

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: DataTable(
           key: table1,
           sortAscending: true,
           columns: <DataColumn>[
             DataColumn(label: Text('AAAA')),
             DataColumn(label: Text('BBBB')),
             ],
           rows: provider.data.results.map((data) =>
              DataRow(
                selected: selectedUsers.contains(data),
                onSelectChanged: (b) {
                   onSelectedRow(b, data);},
           cells: [
            DataCell(Text(data.aaaa)),
            DataCell(Text(data.bbbb)),])).toList(),),),
```

I want to something like call table1 and get rows and cells in it.

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable class has a `rows()` method that will give you the rows. Then, for each row you can access the cells by calling the `cells()` method on the DataRow class.

Check the documentation:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

If you have specific problems, post your code and what you are stuck at.

Comment: Thank you but actually, I didn't get it. :( I added some codes up there.